# How do you "Swipe to go back" in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

There's nothing in the docs about this.

I've just read a blog post on ionics website saying that it's possible to swipe to go back (like ios7) and I've seen the latest ng-conf where they talked about it as well, but nowhere to they mention on how to implement the damn thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do a on-swipe-left. The latest version of Ionic provides this, and is defaults to true. 
As for using this feature, you need to create multiple views, and then just swipe from left, it will take you back to previous view.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has built in gesture events.

Ex.

```html
<div on-swipe-left="swipeleftAction()">
  
  
</div>
```

So I guess you could place on-swipe-left or on-swipe-right in your page container or div.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that handled removing an item from the array of items,

I programatically closed all options buttons by calling

```
$ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
```