# Ionic swipe back gesture enable

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, swipe-gesture, ionic-view

I have the following code:

personal-info.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Personal Information" can-swipe-back="true">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon icon  ion-ios-arrow-left" ng-click="doTheBack()" nav-direction="back"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          There is a fire in <b>sector 3</b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and my controller

```
.controller('PersonalInfoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.doTheBack = function() {
  window.history.back();
};
});
```

I want to enable the swipe back feature I tried by putting `can-swipe-back="true"` inside `<ion-view>` tag but it didn't help at all. Also I have checked a lot of documentation as well as this question [How do you "Swipe to go back" in Ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853904/how-do-you-swipe-to-go-back-in-ionic) but it seems that swipe back feature is not enabled for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I implemented it was through $ionicNavBarDelegate.
In HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Personal Information">
  <ion-content on-swipe-right="swipe('right')" class="padding">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          There is a fire in <b>sector 3</b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.swipe = function (direction) {
                 if(direction == 'right') 
                   $ionicNavBarDelegate.back();
               }
```

Make sure to include $ionicNavBarDelegate in your controller header.

If that doesn't work, take a look at http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/any-sample-code-on-how-to-use-swipe-to-go-back/19122/13. Swipe-to-go-back seems to work by default since RC0 as demonstrated by http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/RNqpJp.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. One more question how can I make it smooth ? Right now its going to the previous screen without any transition.